# How to change background of CKeditor from code behind C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, background, ckeditor

Simple question really. How can I change the background color of the CKeditor from C#?

How do I get an instance of CKeditor in C#? Probably I cannot?

I have a gridview with lots of textareas (asp:textbox) controls all using the CKeditor, via the `CSSclass` property, and it works great! But now I want to dynamically change one or two, or all of their background colours to something like `LightYellow`.

I've tried to directly change the background of the `asp:textbox`, but it doesn't work of course because that's "hidden" from the CKeditor itself.

Any other tips please?

**UPDATE**

I've downloaded the CKEditor for ASP.net and it too **does not work**, as it also creates a `textarea` element in the background automatically - effectively the same as using the CKeditor natively with `CSSclass=""`.

Referencing the control in C#, I can do that now, which is great so I can get the data and use it in my database, but I still cannot change the CKeditor's background. The CKeditor's BODY element (tested via FireBug), is the one I need to change, but how from C#?

Thanks again

Comment: in `config.js` there will be an option `config.uiColor = 'your-color-code';`

Comment: @Webruster thank you, but I need to change the background from the server, not the client side ie: using C#. And your suggestion changes it for every instance of CKeditor in my program. Thanks anyway

Comment: `CKEDITOR.addCss(' body{ background:red; } ');` works, but it changes the background color for all editor on the page.

Comment: @Fandango68  could you please post your ASP.NET code showing how you used CKEditor in a GridView?  Also, which version of CKEditor are/were you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, be sure you have installed both [CKEditor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CKEditor/) and [CkeditorForASP.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CkeditorForASP.NET/) packages via Nuget.

Afterwards, create an **editor.css** file which will contain only editor related styles such as:

```
.lightYellow {
   background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

On your grid view, bind to OnRowDataBound event and specify base path of CKEditor scripts correctly.

```
<asp:GridView ID="EditorGridView" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="EditorGridView_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="Editor" runat="server" BasePath="~/Scripts/ckeditor" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then you will be able to change the body color as follows:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    CKEditorControl editor = (CKEditorControl)e.Row.FindControl("Editor");
    editor.BodyClass = "lightYellow";
    editor.ContentsCss = ResolveUrl("~/Content/editor.css");
}
```

Comment: Just one question. How can I do the same without creaing a separate .css file?

Comment: I have tried other options -not including javascript usage- and it seems this is the only way using C#.